# Running React + Node.js Application as single container (Dockerfile)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I'm wondering about some (maybe) weird kind of solution to deploy my application, generally I have two `Dockerfile`s where one is dedicated for `react`-based front-end with multi-stage build to use `nginx` as static deployment and the second one `pm2`-based runtime for my `node` application.

I really wanted to avoid serving a static files by `node` since it's not effective, and I'm wondering about way to deploy my application as a single Docker image because in this case, I would like to distribute it, is that possible?

Solution in my mind is to create multi-stage build for `react` and `node`, where I'll run `node` application in the background and start `nginx` process which will proxy API to `{url}/api/*` which is not bad solution IMO, but I wanna heard that somebody had a similar idea to do such thing.

Comment: You can [run multiple services in a container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) if it fits your needs.

Comment: I'd compile the React app to static files and have _something_ serve those; I'd prefer to have the Node back-end serve the static files than try to stuff multiple processes into one container.  A multi-stage build doesn't help you get around Docker fundamentally running one process per container.

Comment: I messed in architecture,  and this question seems invalid. The thing that I want to archive is MVC Architecture, where API and Client are parsed in one application, I've found a nice `node` framework which allows us to do such thing called `meteor`.

Comment: In `Dockerfile` there should be no two processes running I think, so I just researched that that should be not done in such way, because when I have `SPA` and `API` that should be two containers, If I would develop `react` as `MVP` application combined with ex. `express` it would be available to build an application in one container, but I don't like this method since `express` with `react` as view controller is messy and performance is really lower than in `SPA` + `API` architecture.

Comment: Anyway, that's ya'll response, I'll try to write an answer to my question and mark it as solved since it's no longer relevant. Maybe somebody in future will try to do such question and this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My research about building multi-process `Dockerfile` is well... damn simple, you should not do that - because containers was indented with `single-process` in mind. In my case I've resolved the issue posted in topic by implementation of `SSR` with `next.js` and before by using tools intended for building monolithic containers like `meteor.js`.

Of course it can be done in a little broken way, with `mult-stage` build where you're bundling `react.js` code and then moving it to another process to be served with `express` as static build, I would not recommend that to everybody since that's unscalable and we can archive better performance by using `nginx` for serving `react.js` build.